# select video from gallery not working in Oreo

Tags: android, android-8.1-oreo

I have used following code to pick video from gallery which was working fine until marshmallow but it is not working for oreo it seems

```
    try {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        i.setType("image/* video/*");
        startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have also tried this but did not work

```
     try {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT,
        android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        i.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Can you share error log?

Comment: it is opening gallery but only showing images to select

Comment: Please try this method, https://stackoverflow.com/a/23994787/4394827

Comment: @HemanthSTobi Do you think I have done anything different than your answer?

Comment: `used following code to pick video from gallery which was working fine until marshmallow but it is not working for oreo it seems `.What does not work ? If onActivityResult() is triggered it works and `data.getData()` is the uri for the selected video. Please tell what does not work.

Comment: `i.setType("image/* video/*");` Never saw such a double type.

Comment: @greenapps android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        i.setType("image/* video/*");
        startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);  is opening gallery but showing only image to choose not videos

Comment: Put that in your post please. You should have started with it.

Answer (score 0):

try this ..

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("video/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Video"),REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO);

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                // OI FILE Manager
                filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

                // MEDIA GALLERY
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                if (selectedImagePath != null) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                            VideoplayAvtivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("path", selectedImagePath);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // UPDATED!
    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            // HERE YOU WILL GET A NULLPOINTER IF CURSOR IS NULL
            // THIS CAN BE, IF YOU USED OI FILE MANAGER FOR PICKING THE MEDIA
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: tried this code and selectedImagePath is null in this case.

Comment: Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video:24653 flg=0x1 }

Comment: `tried this code and selectedImagePath is null in this case` You should not even try to get a 'path' to begin with. Use the content scheme directly! What is is what you try to do that you think you need a 'path'?

Comment: I am trying to pick a file from gallery then play it inside my app later user can upload this video to aws.  For that I am generating video file from the URI that I get from intent Data onActivityResult.

Answer (score 0):

> It is a Permission Issue Please provide `Manifest.permission.CAMERA`,`Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`,`Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`
>
> Permissions

Prior to Android 8.0 (API level 26), if an app requested a permission at runtime and the permission was granted, the system also incorrectly granted the app the rest of the permissions that belonged to the same permission group, and that were registered in the manifest.

For apps targeting Android 8.0, this behavior has been corrected. The app is granted only the permissions it has explicitly requested. However, once the user grants a permission to the app, all subsequent requests for permissions in that permission group are automatically granted.

For example, suppose an app lists both READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in its manifest. The app requests READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and the user grants it. If the app targets API level 25 or lower, the system also grants WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE at the same time, because it belongs to the same STORAGE permission group and is also registered in the manifest. If the app targets Android 8.0 (API level 26), the system grants only READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE at that time; however, if the app later requests WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, the system immediately grants that privilege without prompting the user
[Source link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html)

> But You have to provide permission for read and write external storage.
>   for me it's working